# How can this linear map be injective?

Tags: tensor-products, topological-vector-spaces, locally-compact-groups

Studying the Peter-Weyl theorem, I've come across the following linear maps:

$\theta_E: E'\otimes E \rightarrow$ Hom$(E,E)$

Where $ E'\otimes E$ denotes the tensor product of a finite-dimensional vector space $E$ and its dual $E'$.
Hom$(E,E)$ denotes the set of operators of $E$.

$\theta_E (v \otimes x) \ (y) = v(y)x = \langle v, y\rangle x$, that is, the value of $v$ at $y$ times $x$.

Chapter 3 of Hofmann, K. - The Structure of compact groups says that this linear map is an isomorphism, that is, bijective.

But can this be injective? If you choose $v = 0 \in E'$ we get that for ANY $x \in E$ the value of $\theta$.

$\theta_E(v\otimes x) (y) = 0(y)x = \langle 0, y \rangle x = 0$. Note that this is the linear map $0:E \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ at every $y \in E$
So the kernel

$Ker \  \theta_E$ contains   $0 \otimes E$ as a subspace and so, $\theta_E$ cannot be injective.

What am I seeing wrong here? I mean, even wikipedia says this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have $v=0$, then for any $x\in E$

$v\otimes x=0$.

That is, $0\otimes E$ is trivial.

In more detail, let $\cdot$ denote the scalar product. If $v=0$ then we have

$0\otimes x= (0\cdot 0)\otimes x=0\cdot(0\otimes x)=0\otimes(0\cdot x)=0\otimes 0$.

The two equalities in the middle follow from the definition of the tensor product.

Comment: Are you sure? Is that part of the definition of tensor product? I can't really "see" this being true.

Comment: It's not explicitly part of the definition, but it can be shown. If $v=0$:

$0\otimes x=(0*0)\otimes x=0(0\otimes x) =0\otimes 0x = 0\otimes 0 $

Comment: In the second term, is the star the operation of convolution?

Comment: Sorry, no, that was a typo. It was supposed to be the scalar product. I've expanded my original answer.

Comment: I see. I didn't know you could do such argument. 
Thank you very much. You've helped a lot.